# Is there a simple way to solve content negotiation in Spring boot

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, contenttype

We plan to use content type negitiation as a form of versioning for our rest API but it seems more complex than it should be.
Given the follwing example code :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
ProductController {
.......
@RequestMapping(value = "/{productID}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "productVersion2/json")
public ResponseEntity<ProductV2> getVersion2(@PathVariable String productID) {
.......
return new ResponseEntity<ProductV2>(product, HttpStatus.OK);
```

The correct method is being called when test this from e.g postman, but i get a HTTP 406 Not Acceptable as a response. I have been looking several places, but I have not found a a page with a good explanation of what i need to do to make this work.

The response is to be parsed with json just like all other requests, but the response object is modified. 
The thought is that we by doing this can support several "versions" of the same API and we can gradually make clients move over to the new api, while still having the same uri/resource to access.

Can anyone point to a good tutirial or a step by step guide of how this can be solved in spring boot ?

I have read this article : http://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc/#combined-controller
but I was not able to get a clear anderstanding of what was needed to make it work

Comment: Do you have an `Accept: productVersion2/json` header in the request sent via Postman?

Comment: yes i do. And as mentioned, the call is directed to the correct method in the controller, but it fails in the last method call when i try to return 
        new ResponseEntity<ProductV2>(product, HttpStatus.OK);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your media type is wrong. To use custom media types for API versioning you could use `application/productVersion2+json` instead of `productVersion2/json`. I suspect you get the 406 because Spring Boot has no way to find out how to serialize your object into JSON because `productVersion2/json` isn't a valid media type for json data.

There is more than one way to pick a media type to do this, I've googled a more comprehensive document [here](http://www.narwhl.com/2015/03/the-ultimate-solution-to-versioning-rest-apis-content-negotiation/).

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now :) frustrating that something this simple could stop me, but francly I have not found many resources describing this problem are. Great articlle you found by the way . Shared it with a buch of colegues at work :)